# Como puxar os dados de um Login

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

Preciso puxar o valor do 'nível' que está no banco pois estou definindo em algumas paginas a questão da permissão de acesso , só que não estou conseguindo puxar esse dado da tabela . Alguém pode me ajudar porfavor ?

Segue meu código de conexão :

```
 <?php 
session_start();
            $serverName = "";
            $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"", "UID"=>"", "PWD"=>"" );
            $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
                 if ($conn === false) {
                  die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

 $user = $_POST['email'];
 $password = $_POST['password'];

 $query = ("SELECT LOGIN,SENHA,NIVEL FROM NOME_TABELA WHERE LOGIN LIKE '$user' AND SENHA LIKE '$password'");
 $params = array(); 
 $options = array('Scrollable' => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET);
  $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query, $params, $options);
  $row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows($stmt);
        if ($row_count > 0) {
               session_start();
               $_SESSION['email'] = $user;
               $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
                    header('location:inicio.php');
    }
        else {
    //Destrói
    session_destroy();

    //Limpa
    unset ($_SESSION['email']);
    unset ($_SESSION['password']);


    //Redireciona para a página de autenticação
    header('location:index.php');

}
?>
```

Comment: Amigo, poste o código na pergunta e não um print

Comment: Não tava sabendo como formatar por isso tinha enviado via foto , mas já foi alterado

Comment: pode explicar melhor o *"não estou conseguindo puxar esse dado da tabela"*? o que acontece, algum erro?

Comment: Então , eu tenho 3 colunas na minha tabela ( Usuário / senha / nível ) preciso da variável "nível" que está associada ao usuário para poder fazer restrição de acesso em algumas determinadas paginas. Só que eu não consigo puxar esse valor . Ele não retorna a nada . to aprendendo PHP agora , sou meio leigo . Ai to me batendo pra puxar esse dado .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crie uma variável associando os dados do usuário a uma array e pegue o valor do NIVEL:

```
if ($row_count > 0) {
   $dados = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
   $_SESSION['email'] = $user;
   $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
   $_SESSION['nivel'] = $dados["NIVEL"];
   header('location:inicio.php');
}else{
   ...
}
```

**[Documentação](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php)**

Comment: Obrigado cara Funcionou aqui .